# DynamoDB Search with HashKey

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk

I have table with the following structure

```
HashKey: Place Name
Attribute: Place Data Class
```

now i would like to search with Place Name,

Ex: I have below data

`Newyork           {lat: x.xxxxx, lng: x.xxxxxx}
Newzealand        {lat: x.xxxxx, lng: x.xxxxxx}
IndialaPolis      {lat: x.xxxxx, lng: x.xxxxxx}`

when i searching with keyword `new`, it should return Newyork and Newzealand, I searched google for this, i found that we can get all records by the HashKey

Comment: DynamoDB doesn't support querying the HashKey for a partial match like this. You probably need to look into indexing your data in something like Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks & i have a doubt, is that data permanent & can i store some aggregate data in Elastic Search

Comment: @MarkB can you please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41513677/4234949

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @mark-b and @bruno-buccolo, as you said it is not possible to Search hashkey field

So i created Elastic Search Indexes for that table manually and updating each time the original record updates

Answer (score 2):

When doing a `Query`, you can only have exact matches on the `HashKey`.

However, there is also the `Scan` operation, that you can use along with a `FilterExpression`. Just note that `Query` and `Scan` perform and consume capacity differently. [See the differences here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html).

Here are example parameters you could use on a `Scan` with `begins_with`:

```
{
    table_name: tableName,
    filter_expression: "begins_with(#country, :search)",
    expression_attribute_names: {
        "#country" => "country"
    },
    expression_attribute_values: {
        ":search" => "new" 
    }
}
```

This [article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html) is a good place to start.

Comment: But `scan` operation scans `whole table` if the table has more rows it is very difficult do `scan` operation each time user searching, so i'm going to use elastic search as @MarkB suggested,

If i'm wrong, can you please explain more thanks

Comment: You're correct, `scan` goes through the whole table. However, if this is only the list of all countries in the world, you should be fine. You should also note that there is a replication lag from `Dynamo` to `ElasticSearch`. If as soon as you insert an item on `Dynamo` you query `ElasticSearch` it might not be there. Again, if this is a list of all countries, you should be fine too because countries don't change that often.

Comment: It is not a static list, the list will be updated as users starts using the application, so i tried to use eastic search, and i manually added the items to index in elastic search when an new item inserted, and it working fine now. Can you please explain more about the replication lag - i can't find any way to set replication to dynamodb and elastic search, how can i setup the replication for dynamodb and elastic search